# SQL Linked Server returns no rows when ran via SQL Job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, jobs

I have a TSQL stored procedure that runs just fine when I execute via SSMS query window.  This stored procedure utilizes a linked server.

However, when I run the stored procedure via SQL Job, whether it's on-demand or scheduled, it returns 0 results (all the selects are from the linked server).  The job DOES run, however, because the first line in the SP truncates the table.  And when I view the Job History, it says it's successful.

I'm guessing this is a permissions issue but I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With no more details than "it works sometimes and not others" we can't do anything to help either.

Comment: The stored procedure works when I run via SSMS query, but it doesn't work when I run it via SQL job.  It's technically "successful" according to the Job History, but it can't get data from a linked server. I don't know what other information you'd need here.  Please be so kind to let me know what information you're missing.

Comment: Did you run it in SSMS as the user for the job? That would be the first step in debugging this. Maybe the parameters are different? Who knows? I can't see your screen so I have no idea how to even steer you here. If it is a permissions issue you should get an error message. Or does your sql job have an error handler that prevents any logging of errors? There are SO many thing this could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the SQL Agent not having permissions to Dynamics CRM 2011 filtered views.  We will either bypass the filtered views and hit the direct tables, change the linked server properties to a CRM user that has permission, or create a CRM user for the SQL Agent user.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this sounds like a permission issue - you are able to run it fine in SSMS because your login (presumably) has access to both servers, but the default SQL Agent Server login doesn't have access to the linked server - so it can run the Stored Procedure but with no access to the linked server it returns no data.

I'd take a look into creating a SQL Server Agent Proxy account - this allows you to use a login for a SQL Job that both has permission to run the stored procedure as well as access to the linked server.  Just make sure that whatever login you use has the correct access on both servers.

Here's the MS TechNet link on how to create a proxy account:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190698(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Jericho, thanks for your response.  I forgot to mention, the linked server is actually just another instance on the same SQL server.  We have CRM data on the default instance, and the job & stored procedure live on the \BI instance.  Both instances have SQLadmin@mydomain.local set as the "Log On As" for SQL Server Agent.